# How to use openJDK instead of Oracle JDK in team city build agent?

Tags: teamcity

How to use openJDK instead of Oracle JDK in team city build agent? My team city build agent is currently using Oracle JDK 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install OpenJDK
2. Change teamcity config file on build agent server. it must be having path for Oracle JDK, replace path with OpenJDK.
3. now you can uninstall Oracle JDK.
4. Restart teamcity service on build agent.